# Security consequences due to setting `set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);`

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, boost, boost-asio

I'm using [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) as a template in a server/client pair I wrote. I honestly don't understand all the details on how the secure connection is done. I understand the simple private/public RSA encryption. We encrypt with a public key, and only private keys can open it. Is it as simple here? (this is not the real question here)

**So my question is:** In my client part I used `set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);`. Does this jeopardize the secure connection I'm using? Is the connection still secure and encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not safe setting SSL_VERIFY_NONE. In this case if someone attack the connection the client won't be able to verify the sender's identity.

Detailed description of server and client behaviour for each flags on openssl site:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html

Comment: So it's not safe only for the case of a man-in-the-middle-attack? It doesn't affect encryption?

Comment: It doesn't affect encryption. Setting SSL_VERIFY_NONE means only that the client doesn't verify the certificate of the server before creating the encrypted channel.

Comment: The data will be encrypted.  But you can't tell where it came from, so any number of snoops could occur before the channel you receive.  So although the data is encrypted, you can't tell if it came from the client, or was re-transmitted by men-in-the-middle.